# Any reason to use the Android Device Emulator?

Tags: android, development-environment

Obviously the Android Device Emulator is super slow. I was told that even if I mega-bump up my ram it will still be slow. So am currently using a physical android tablet.

So is there ever a "solid" reason to use the emulator? Or can in develop happily away without it?

Many thanks ahead.

Comment: "Obviously the Android Device Emulator is super slow" -- that depends a lot on your development machine and your choice of emulator CPU architecture. "I was told that even if I mega-bump up my ram it will still be slow" -- nobody on the planet knows what "mega-bump" means to you. I can tell you that an Ubuntu notebook, with a Core i7 CPU (turbo-boost to ~3.4GHz), 8GB RAM, and an SSD runs the x86 emulator fairly well. The emulator boots a bit slow, but so do devices.

Comment: "So is there ever a "solid" reason to use the emulator?" -- if you have devices for every OS version and a couple of screen sizes, you can go a long way with hardware. I rarely fire up an emulator, personally, but I have ~50 devices in my lab. However, a few things (e.g., Hierarchy View) work better with an emulator. Plus, emulators can be "factory reset" very easily and are therefore more disposable.

Comment: Try Genymotion. Google should officially implement Genymotion in AS instead of AVD.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons falls on the obvious: if you don't have **ANY** physical device.

The other strong reason is to be able to simulate environments you don't have in your device. Different android versions, different screens sizes and densities, etc.

PS: Genymotion is fast enough to be a good option to develop using emulators, and the latest versions of Android Studio and AVD seem to integrate pretty decently x86 emulators, which also increase the overall speed. I've been working with this last choice for over a week with acceptable results. Anyway, nothing can compare to a physical device.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more performant when you use windows virtualization technology that is supported by Intel Processors. This has to be enabled in the BIOS. It will significantly speed up the performance of the emulator. Additionally you can freeze the running Emulation to a snapshot, that can be loaded without rebooting the complete device.

Another point is you can use several device configuration, screen resolutions and other android versions. In some cases you want to test the features of newer Android versions without buying a new device.

Answer (score 0):

- Emulators maintain the original look, feel, and behavior of the
         physical android phone
- No need to buy android phone
- No need to worry that you will destroy your ‘phone’

Android Studio 2.0 is latest release of the official Android IDE focused on build performance and emulator speed to improve the app development experience.

Android Emulator - **[Brand new emulator](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/12/android-studio-20-preview-android.html)** that is faster than most real devices, and includes a brand new user interface.

**[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)** is faster then android old emulator.The Genymotion emulator uses x86 architecture virtualization and OpenGL hardware acceleration which makes running your apps more efficient.